# Java и реестр windows

Tags: windows, реестр, java

Читал в интернете, что можно работать с реестром с помощью библиотеки `deploy.jar`, но конкретных примеров записи и чтения из реестра найти не удалось. Точнее говоря, нашёл только этот кусок кода, который неизвестно что делает. Огромная просьба помочь с этим вопросом.

```
String ab[] = WinRegistryWrapper.WinRegGetValues(WinRegistryWrapper.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "\\Software\\ODBC\\ODBC.IN\\pay", 100);
    for (int i = 0; i < ab.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(ab[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WinRegGetValues` получает значение из реестра по указанному пути и кидает всю эту информацию в массив строк ab. После чего циклом мы выводим всю эту информацию на экран.

Comment: Спасибо, а Вы не могли бы привести примеры записи и чтения из реестра? Большое спасибо за помощь.